# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string in toad oracle

Tags: database, oracle, date

```
INSERT INTO USERTASK (USERTASKKEY,USERID,TASKKEY,TASKDATE,CREATEDATE,CREATEUSERID) VALUES (USERTASKSEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,'admin45','1', TO_DATE('2015-06-25 15:53','yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE('2015-06-01 15:53:22','yyyy/mm/dd'),'admin')
Error at line 1
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

this is the code i get from the insert statement of my program. and i copy and paste it into TOAD and it throw me this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the time component to the date mask:

```
TO_DATE('2015-06-01 15:53:22','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```